# How we can hiding advertising messages of the WordPress plugins?

Tags: wordpress

I have install the different plugins for the my wordpress project but, i want to hide the promotional or advertising messages of that plugins.

I was tried by using display none property of css but it wont work for me.

```
id{
  display:none;
}
```

I don't want to be showcase the that promotional messages please suggest me what can i do ?

Comment: It's likely that removing the advertising would violate the TOS/usage requirements of those plugins, no? In any case, the plugin developer would be your first resource.

Comment: Try this artical https://www.wpoptimus.com/626/7-ways-disable-update-wordpress-notifications/

Comment: Let me confirm only it is possible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

## id .class {display:none !important;}

```html
#id .class {display:none !important;}
```